# Find outlier after data fit in R

Tags: r, data-fitting

My problem is a combination of my basic statistical understanding and handling it in R.

**The situation:**
I have 191 different types that are seen in a general environment (column "general"). Only a subset are capable of getting into the special environment (column "special").
I suspect a linear relationship between the two - the more frequent something is, the more often it will advance into the special environment.

My question is: are there some cases where they advance more often than normal?
I think the "normal" is found by fitting a model. In that sense, I believe that my question is answered by finding outliers from my model. Is that correct?

**The data&code:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sfsmisc)
n <- c(1:191)
general <- c(1, 7, 4, 11, 6, 11, 102, 19, 18, 1, 17, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 20, 
5, 3, 10, 4, 8, 15, 35, 3, 12, 4, 9, 1, 18, 3, 7, 53, 5, 1, 33, 6, 10, 39, 6, 16, 10, 
1, 27, 3, 61, 100, 2, 5, 16, 30, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 60, 12, 2, 2, 13, 20, 14, 17, 
16, 2, 1, 7, 3, 1, 10, 8, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 25, 2, 61, 22, 45, 4, 31, 4, 3, 47, 
4, 1, 5, 2, 2, 30, 84, 136, 14, 1, 1, 15, 1, 1, 1, 124, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 40, 192, 3, 
1, 22, 3, 1, 26, 1, 36, 132, 6, 4, 9, 201, 4, 43, 180, 98, 3, 1, 3, 11, 82, 83, 5, 
10, 3, 2, 10, 23, 2, 25, 50, 4, 35, 2, 2, 3, 10, 18, 3, 2, 2, 13, 8, 5, 11, 28, 11, 
3, 4, 11, 3, 74, 56, 5, 13, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 9, 12, 4, 47, 13, 131, 1, 3, 1)
special <- c(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 30, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1, 0, 7, 16, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 18, 1, 0, 
8, 3, 2, 10, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 1, 13, 23, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 15, 2, 1, 0, 4, 10, 7, 4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 12, 0, 14, 4, 17, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 14, 37, 52, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 47, 
1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 10, 0, 6, 27, 2, 0, 2, 57, 1, 8, 67, 36, 1, 0, 
0, 2, 23, 18, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 4, 8, 0, 7, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 30, 12, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 16, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0)
```

I combine them into a dataframe, plot them and add the linear model. It seems to fit pretty well: [scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRv9d.png)

```
d.combined <- data.frame(n=n, general=general, special=special)
ggplot(d.combined , aes(x=general, y=special)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F)
```

The linear model looks good, R-squared is high, p-value is low:

```
lm_comb <- lm(special~general, d.combined)
summary.lm(lm_comb)

#Residual standard error: 3.023 on 189 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.9232,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.9228 
#F-statistic:  2273 on 1 and 189 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Going with the Cook's distance I can see that there are 7 clear outliers, which is perfect and even fits what I know from previous data.

```
cooksdc <- cooks.distance(lm_comb)
plot(cooksdc, cex=0.5)
abline(h = 4*mean(cooksdc, na.rm=T), col="red")
text(x=1:length(cooksdc)+1, y=cooksdc,
labels=ifelse(cooksdc>4*mean(cooksdc, na.rm=T), names(cooksdc), ""), col="red")
```

[Cook's distance plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53N50.png)

I also used the outliers package and (mis)used the scores() function with t, z and chi squared tests. They find 11 outliers for the last and 12 for the first two tests, all at 95% probability. They all make sense, too.

But the Tukey-Anscombe plot shows a cone towards the right, which means it is not linear. Right?

```
TA.plot(lm_comb) #requires sfsmisc package
```

[TA plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP8BJ.png)

**The questions:**

- Am I on the right track? I.e., does my approach in principle even work for my question? Am I interpreting the TA plot correctly? Why does the linear regression give me such a high Rsquared when the TA plot indicates non-linearity?
- What options do I have to fit an apparently non-linear model? How?
- Do I *have* to do that or is there another solution?

Comment: There don't seem to be any programming questions here which is what Stack Overflow is for. If you need help interpreting or performing a statistical analysis, you should be asking over at [stats.se], not here.

Comment: I saw it as combination of both. But you are probably correct in that I should first ask the question about statistics and then later how to implement it. I was hoping though that the large overlap between the users of R and crossvalidated might make that unnecessary. Thanks anyway!